# True False Statements (Group Theory )

Tags: group-theory

Let $G_1$ be an Abelian group of order $6$ and $G_2$ = $S_3$.

**a.** Both $G_1$  and $G_2$ have unique subgroup of order $2$.

**b.**  Neither $G_1$  and $G_2$ have unique subgroup of order $2$.

**c.** $G_1$ has but not $G_2$ a unique subgroup of order $2$.

**d.** $G_2$ has but not $G_1$ a unique subgroup of order $2$.

> For $G_1$ I thought of taking $\mathbb{Z}_6$ , so it has Abelian group of order $2$ .But i am just verifying and not cutting options down, hence not sure . For $S_3$ I don't know how to explicitly write subgroups.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on them?

Comment: @Henrik For $G_1$ i thought of taking $Z_6$ , so it has abelian group of order 2 .But i am just verifying and not cutting options down ,hence not sure  . For $S_3$ i donot know how to explicitely write subgroups .

Comment: In the statements $G_1$ can be any abelian group of order 6, so taking any particular group is only useful for finding counterexamples, You can't really use the fact that there exists an abelian group of order 6 with a subgroup of order 2 for anything. Maybe it would help you to look at $S_3$ and look for an element that can generate a subgroup of order 2?

Comment: @Henrik In $S_3 $ many elements generate group of order 2 .But how to do for $S_1$